# What's the covariance structure for standard repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures, covariance-matrix

This question arose when failing to replicate a repeated measures ANOVA using a linear mixed effects model. According to textbooks, rmANOVA uses a compound symmetric covariance matrix for the random effects. However I am still having trouble understanding how to replicate a "standard rmANOVA" (e.g. as performed by clicking repeated measures in SPSS) as a LME model (e.g. in lme4).

Let's say we have a typical experimental design for behavioural science: a 2-factor design, with each of the conditions performed in each subject. Each subject is treated identically. I would typically write:

```
response ~ factor1 * factor2 + ( factor1 * factor2 | subject )
```

Let us say that `factor1` and `factor2` each have **four** levels -- a 4x4 design. This is the simplest situation where my confusion arises. The standard rmANOVA yields three F statistics:

```
factor1 + factor2 + factor1:factor2
```

Under the hood, I gather each factor is dummy coded, which usually means there's an intercept, plus three terms for each factor

```
1 + f1a + f1b + f1c
  + f2a + f2b + f2c  + interactions
```

I believe that here, a "covariance matrix" means something like: the degree to which the effects correlate with each other, across different subjects (i.e. levels of the grouping variable). To keep things simple, I'm going to ignore interactions. So its shape is:

```
1      [  s0                            ]
f1a    [      s1a                       ]
f1b    [           s1b                  ]
f1c    [                s1c             ]
f2a    [                    s2a         ]
f2b    [                        s2b     ]
f2c    [                            s2c ]
```

Now what is a compound symmetric matrix? Here is how you might interpret the books:

```
1      [  s0                            ]
f1a    [  c   s1a                       ]
f1b    [  c   c    s1b                  ]
f1c    [  c   c    c    s1c             ]
f2a    [  c   c    c    c   s2a         ]
f2b    [  c   c    c    c   c   s2b     ]
f2c    [  c   c    c    c   c   c   s2c ]
```

But if doesn't make much sense why all these would have the same correlation. A more sensible option might be

```
1      [  s0                            ]
f1a    [      s1a                       ]
f1b    [      c1   s1b                  ]
f1c    [      c1   c1   s1c             ]
f2a    [                    s2a         ]
f2b    [                    c2  s2b     ]
f2c    [                    c2  c2  s2c ]
```

So the levels of a single factor are allowed to correlate. Here, the spaces are constrained to zero. Perhaps a more 'unconstrained' version would be:

```
1      [  s0                            ]
f1a    [  c01 s1a                       ]
f1b    [  c01 c11  s1b                  ]
f1c    [  c01 c11  c11  s1c             ]
f2a    [  c02 c12  c12  c12 s2a         ]
f2b    [  c02 c12  c12  c12 c22 s2b     ]
f2c    [  c02 c12  c12  c12 c22 c22 s2c ]
```

which appears to have five covariance terms, `c01 c02 c11 c22 c12`. It allows the effects of all the factors to correlate across individuals, but retains compound symmetry within factors. Here, I constrain the correlation for all the factor1 levels to factor 2 levels to all be identical - (i.e. `c12` always the same) and the intercept to all factor 1 levels to be identical (`c01`). But again this constraint can be relaxed, while retaining compound symmetry **just within** factors.

So these are at least 4 different possibilities. **Which one is "standard" rmANOVA doing?** (if any) - Or perhaps I have completely misunderstood what the covariance matrix mean here?